# Sackur-Tetrode Classical vs Quantum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Referencing these sources in studying the Sackur-Tetrode equation: chapter 4 of [these stat. mech lecture notes](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/s12/lecture-notes/chapter04.pdf), and Pathria Stat. Mech 3rd Edition. They approach deriving the Sackur-Tetrode equation in different ways. To summarize their methods:

- Lecture notes (classical): Explicitly calculate $\Omega$ using the Hamilton for an ideal gas. Divide by $h^{3N}$, ad hoc, in order to align result with the quantum derivation
- Pathria (quantum): model the classical gas as quantum particles in a box, with zero potential inside the box

In both cases I assume that we are appropriately dividing by $N!$, as I am not directly interested in Gibbs' Paradox in this question.

Both derivations use similar mathematics, namely finding the volume of a $3N$ dimensional sphere to enumerate the total number of states for all energies $\leq E$, which is denoted $\Phi$. Both lead to the same result:

$$\Omega(N,V,E,\Delta) = \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial E} \Delta \frac{1}{N!} = \frac{3N\Delta}{2E} \Phi \frac{1}{N!}$$

Therefore,

$$\Omega(N,V,E,\Delta)=\frac{3N\Delta}{2E}\left(\frac{V}{N}\right)^N\left(\frac{E}{N}\right)^{3N/2} \left(\frac{e m}{3\pi \hbar^2}\right)^{3N/2}e^N$$

In Pathria's derivation, he assigns each mode of vibration of the wavefunction, $n$, to a degree of freedom $r$ of a particle in the box. Each particle has 3 degrees of freedom (x, y, z momentum coordinates). The total energy in the box can be defined as:

$$\sum_{r=1}^{3N} E_r = E$$

Where $E_r$ is the energy associated with the momentum component of a particle. For a *single* particle in a box (quantum), we have:

$$E_{particle} = \frac{h^2}{8mV^{2/3}}n^2$$

In the next step Pathria *assigns* each mode of vibration of the wavefunction to a degree of freedom:

$$E_r = \frac{h^2}{8mV^{2/3}}n_r^2$$

And,

$$\sum_{r=1}^{3N} E_r = \frac{h^2}{8mV^{2/3}}\sum_{r=1}^{3N}n_r^2$$

Clearly, we can calculate the volume of a hyper-sphere that has $3N$ coordinates (positive "sector" only, $n \ge 0$), $n_1$ to $n_{3N}$ with radius $R=(8mV^{2/3}E/h^2)^{1/2}$. This ends up being mathematically identical to the classical derivation where we calculate the $3N$ dimensional volume of a sphere with equation $\sum_{i=1}^{3N} p_i^2 = 2mE$.

What is the physical significance of assigning each classical degree of freedom (momentum component of particle energy) to a vibrational mode of the wavefunction?

Is it generally true that a mode of vibration of the wavefunction is associated with a degree of freedom in a system?

It is so striking to me that these two derivations lead to an identical result (except by a factor of $h^{3N}$). Is this because the Hamiltonian is built into the wavefunction?

Comment: Have you learned about systems of bosons and fermions yet?

Comment: I have not. I am currently working through Griffith's Intro to Quantum Mech. I've studied stat mech (and the history of) more extensively.

Comment: There turns out to be a correspondence between the many-body wave functions of identical particles of Bose type and the wave functions of harmonic oscillators (e.g. a vibrating plate or resonant acoustic cavity [phonons], or a resonant electromagnetic cavity [photons], and more.)  The 'excitation' number of an oscillator corresponds to the number of particles occupying the corresponding orbital or energy level.  Pathria is probably using this correspondence to derive the Sackur-Tetrode equation from the classical limit of an ensemble of quantum harmonic oscillators (w/chemical potential.)